# actionbar menu-like in custom dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have a `GridView` with some items and when the user clicks on an item, I show a `DialogFragment` with all the item details. I wanted to know if there is a way to create my own dropdown menu like the ones in the `ActionBar`. Meaning, when the user will click on an `ImageButton` let's say, I would show all the available actions for this item, like deletion, editing etc.

Any ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try PopupMenu. PopupMenu could be used to display a custom dropdown menu which could be anchored to a view
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html